# Returning values from Dynamic PL/SQL to match a basic SELECT FROM statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

This is undoubtedly a very basic Dynamic PL/SQL question, but I am stuck.

I am looking to write a dynamic PL/SQL which will function the same as the code below, returning values of field1, field2, field3 from all rows of tablename:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM databasename.tablename;
```

If I write the following Dynamic SQL, I can get it to successfully execute.  However, I can't get it to return anything:

```
declare
    Query  VARCHAR2(200) := 'SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM databasename.tablename';
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Query;
end;
```

How does one return the results of the Dynamic SQL to match the one-line SELECT statement above, please?

Answer (score 0):

- Your first select statement is sql query and it can return the result as an tabular format.
- But your second code is `anonymous block` and you can not execute any select query in anonumous block without `INTO` clause.

If you know that your select query is going to give you single record then use the `INTO` clause as follows:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Query into var1, var2, var3;
```

**Note**: declare the variables `var1, var2 and var3` in declare section with proper data type.

Comment: Ok thanks. But how can I return all rows, as I asked in the original question? Is there any way to return tabular data from a dynamic SQL to match the output of the first select statement?

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward method to return the dataset from a Query string for your case would be using a cursor within a Stored Function or Procedure with return type `SYS_REFCURSOR` such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Result_Of_TheTable RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  Query       VARCHAR2(200) := 'SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tablename';
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_recordset FOR Query;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

and then call from SQL Developer's console as

```
DECLARE
    result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :result := Get_Result_Of_TheTable;
END;
/

PRINT result;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities. If you know which fields are returned, then you can solve it this way:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE cursor_type IS REF CURSOR;
   l_cursor cursor_type;
   l_record tablename%ROWTYPE;
   l_query  VARCHAR2(32767) := 'SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tablename';
BEGIN
   OPEN l_cursor FOR l_query;
   LOOP
      FETCH l_cursor INTO l_record;
      EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (l_record.field1 ||' '|| l_record.field2 ||' '|| l_record.field3);
   END LOOP;
   
   CLOSE l_cursor;
END;
/
```

Or you can write a small pipelined function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_test
AS
   TYPE test_type IS TABLE
      OF tablename%ROWTYPE;
      
   FUNCTION get_fields
      RETURN test_type PIPELINED;
END pkg_test;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_test
AS    
   FUNCTION get_fields
      RETURN test_type PIPELINED
   AS
      TYPE cursor_type IS REF CURSOR;
      l_cursor cursor_type;
      l_record tablename%ROWTYPE;
      l_query  VARCHAR2(32767) := 'SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tablename';
   BEGIN
      OPEN l_cursor FOR l_query;
      LOOP
         FETCH l_cursor INTO l_record;
         EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
         
         PIPE ROW (l_record);
      END LOOP;
   CLOSE l_cursor;
      
   END;
END pkg_test;
/

SELECT * FROM TABLE(pkg_test.get_fields);
```

This was for my test:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
( field1 VARCHAR2(10),
  field2 VARCHAR2(10),
  field3 VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('A1', 'A2', 'A3');
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('B1', 'B2', 'B3');
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('C1', 'C2', 'C3');

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bulk collect into` clause, like for static SQL in PL/SQL block.

Here is a simple example:

```sql
drop table users_tb;

create table users_tb (
  id           integer      generated always as identity,
  --
  username     varchar2(30) not null,
  is_active    char(1)      default 1 not null,
  created_date date         default sysdate not null ,
  edited_date  date,
  --
  constraint user_id_pk        primary key (id),
  constraint user_is_active_ch check (is_active in (1,0))
);

insert into users_tb (username) values ('john.wick');
insert into users_tb (username) values ('constantine');
insert into users_tb (username) values ('neo');
commit;

declare
  -- types
  type tr_list is record (
    username  varchar2(30),
    is_active integer
  );
  type tt_usernamelist is table of tr_list
    index by pls_integer;
          
  -- variables
  lt_users tt_usernamelist;
  l_stmt   varchar2(2000);
begin
  -- select statement
  l_stmt := 'select username, is_active from users_tb';
                     
  -- execution of dynamic code
  execute immediate l_stmt 
    bulk collect into lt_users;
  
  -- loop over retrived data
  for i in 1..lt_users.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line('User: '||lt_users(i).username||' - Is active: '||lt_users(i).is_active);
  end loop;
end;
```

The important part is the `execution of dynamic code` where I am using `bulk collect into`. Here is a link to [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f82109e3fe2b14c46322cdecf1055f60) to try out.